# Extend my JavaScript Code

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've made a horizontal menu that works like a tab-changer on click.

I want to add some code to JavaScript that will take one other div `id="rest"` and close it (make it hidden) the same time when I change my first (active) tab. I attached an image to better explain my situation: [My page design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ug5EL.jpg)

I just need that when `div id="defaultOpen"` is changed, that one other div with `id="rest"` be hidden.

```js
 function openCity(evt, cityName) {
   var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
   tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
   for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
     tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
   }
   tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
   for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
     tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
   }
   document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
   evt.currentTarget.className += " active";

   var active = "defaultOpen";
   if (tab_id === 'defaultOpen') {
     document.getElementById('rest').style.display = "none";
   } else {
     document.getElementById('rest').style.display = "block";
   }

 }

 document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <ul style="list-style: none; padding: 0;">
    <li>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')" id="defaultOpen">
        <div class="tab-active">
          <img src="img/appoitments-active.png">
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="active" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">
        <div class="tab">
          <img src="img/prescription.png">
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="" onclick="openCity(event, 'Madrid')">
        <div class="tab">
          <img src="img/health.png">
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="" onclick="openCity(event, 'Rome')">
        <div class="tab">
          <img src="img/uploads.png">
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">
        <div class="tab">
          <img src="img/medical.png">
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Can you please help me with this?

Thank you very much for your help.

Regards

Comment: I don't see any id="rest" in your html. Also, no classNames of tabcontent, tablinks and active.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by using Javascript DOM event listeners.

```
// Function to add event listener to table

var el = document.getElementById("prescription"); //(Name your #ID here)
el.addEventListener("click", function(){document.getElementById('rest').style.display = "block";}, false);
```

Here you can see the [example](https://jsfiddle.net/api/mdn/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by your description of requirements. I've looked at your design. Please confirm if this is what the expectations are:

Page load =
There are 5 (div id=rest) elements. One for each top level tab. All of the (div id=rest) elements are hidden except for the first top tab that is active.

User clicks top tab 2 =
The existing visible (div id=rest) element becomes hidden. The 2nd (div id=rest) element becomes visible and so forth.

If that is your requirement then:

1. Don't name your (div id=rest), name them (div class=rest rest) (div class=rest rest2) (div class=rest rest3) etc  because there should only ever be one id on the page.
2. For each (div class=tab), add an attribute, (div class=tab data-controls=rest1). (div class=tab data-controls=rest2) Corresponding to the div rest you want to show.
3. Inside your function you can get the attribute of the current tab and target that (div class=rest) to open.